# Formality and usage of といった

Tags: grammar, formality, particle-など

I've just learnt that AといったB means "B such as A". I was wondering how this differed in formality/usage/popularity from AなどのB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In technical contexts, などの is preferred because it's unambiguous.

  > アルカリ金属、金、銀などの電気伝導性の高い金属は超伝導にならない。
- といった meaning "such as" is usually used when there are two (or more) instances, in the form `A や B (や C) といった`.
- といった is preferred when you make light of the listed things (i.e. "such things as ～").

  > 私はリアリストなので、夢や希望といった話には興味がない。